# PHP - Temp File Path is null

Tags: php

I have a script that handles file uploads. I have uploaded files that are under 1 MB, but when the file is over 1 MB the script seems set the temporary file path to null. Here is the script below:

```
$total = count($_FILES['DocName']['tmp_name']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {

        // Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['DocName']['tmp_name'][$i];

        // Check if we have a path
        if ($tmpFilePath != "") {

            // Variables from form
            $FolderName = $_POST['FolderName'];
            $FolderName = stripslashes($FolderName);
            $FolderName = mysql_real_escape_string($FolderName);

            //Setup our new file path

            // Check if folder name is home, if so, set the file path to that folder
            if ($FolderName == "Home") {
                $target_dir = "../../cdn.brmbc.com/usercontent/".$UserID."/";
            }

            // If the folder name is not home, make the file go to that folder
            else {
                $IsInFolder = 1;
                $target_dir = "../../cdn.brmbc.com/usercontent/".$UserID."/".$FolderName."/";
            }

            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["DocName"]["name"][$i]);
            $FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $DocumentName = $_FILES["DocName"]["name"][$i];

            echo $tmpFilePath . "<br>";
            echo $target_file . "<br>";
            echo $FileType . "<br>";
            echo $DocumentName . "<br>";
        }

        // Go home if there is no temp path
        else {
            echo $tmpFilePath . "<br>" . "Failed to upload";
        }
    }
```

Does there appear to be anything incorrect about the code, or is this just a server issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your uploads work for files under 1MB I'm guessing it's a php.ini setting.

If you have access to your php.ini search for a setting called "max_file_uploads" - I bet it's set to 1MB.

http://php.net/upload-max-filesize

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the php.ini file. In php.ini file you will find

```
upload_max_filesize=2M
```

something like this. There you have to increase the filesize. I think your's is like

```
upload_max_filesize=1M
```

After increasing the filesize it should be okey.